# AssemblyScript export name with space in its label

Tags: assemblyscript

I need to export a label pointing to a function like

```
(func $can_sayhello (export "can sayhello") (type $t3)
```

The closest I can get is:

```
 (export "can_sayhello" (func $assembly/index/can_sayhello))
```

using this AssemblyScript

```
@external("can sayhello")
export declare function can_sayhello(): void;
```

What I really want to do is change the label of this function

```
function sayhello() : void {
}
//output in wat
(export "sayhello" (func $assembly/index/sayhello))
```

to be

```
 (export "can sayhello" (func $assembly/index/sayhello))
```

I'm new to assembly script and I really cant figure this out, if you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty unusual for any language to have function names with spaces, but it is possible!

I wrote a simple transformation pass that allows you have any string for named exports.

It is here https://github.com/willemneal/visitor-as/blob/master/src/examples/exportAs.ts

You need to add `visitor-as` as a dependency for your project then either in your `asconfig.json` or cli add the `exportAs` transformer.

e.g.

```
@exportAs("can sayhello")
export function main(): u32 {
  return 42;
}
```

Then compile like

```
asc assembly/index.ts --transform visitor-as/dist/examples/exportAs
```

Comment: No idea why I did not get this notification! I was not aware how extensive visitor-as was but always knew I needed to use it.  Thank you!